# conditional sum of one column based on another and then all grouped by a third

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Assume a table like this:

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| a | 1 | 1 |
| a | 4 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 1 |
| b | 6 | 3 |
| a | 4 | 6 |
| b | 2 | 7 |
```

I want to get the sum of `B` for different bands of `C` grouped by `A`. I can do it by making a new column per band in an inner query that has ones when I want to sum values and zeros where I don't like this:

```
SELECT A, SUM(B*band_1) as band_1, SUM(B*band_2) as band_2
FROM (SELECT A,
             B,
             CASE 
               WHEN C <= 5 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END as band_1,
             CASE 
               WHEN C > 5 and C <= 10 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END as band_2
       FROM MyTable) as T
GROUP BY A
```

Which works. But when I have a lot of bands, this query will grow quite unwieldy. Is there some clever method to do this better? Maybe using `PIVOT` or dynamic SQL or even OLAP or something?

Comment: oh i like the question

Comment: Do you have a pattern for those bands? Do you know how many bands will be before query?

Comment: @EricZ I'm not sure if there would be a pattern but I would definitely know the bands before hand. If you have a solution that relies on a pattern it still might be worth seeing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a sub-query, if you don't have a pattern for bands, maybe try this way

```
SELECT  A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C <= 5 THEN B ELSE 0 END) as band_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C > 5 and C <= 10 THEN B ELSE 0 END) as band_2
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY A
```

Comment: Yup - I was being stupid. Also I checked, there is a pattern. It's <=5, 5 - 15, 15 - 25 etc... Is there a clever way to do that? I've never tried loops in TSQL